# Sharepoint online and InfoPath publishing problems

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, form

I have this problem happen all the time with my InfoPath forms and form libraries.  I log into my SP Online account in IE.  I go to the form library / Settings / Advanced settings and click Edit Template.  I make modifications to the template, save it to my computer, and then try to either Publish or Quick Publish.  I get this error most of the time.  Does anyone know what causes this?  I'm still logged into my account.  I added my tenant as a trusted site.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks
[image: InfoPath publishing problem]

Comment: Rather than saving the InfoPath form to my hard drive, and then publishing it. I saved it to a location on SharePoint and published it from there. Above solution helped to resolve. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Do as the below:

1. Uncheck the “Enable Protected Mode” in IE. Go to IE->Internet Options->Security tab-> Select “Internet” Zone.
2. When you login to SharePoint Online, check “Keep me signed in”.

Reference:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58700a59-e1d4-42ec-a799-d84091188f9f/infopath-form-publishing-error-access-denied?forum=sharepointcustomization

Answer (score 0):

I realize this an old post, but if you are like me, and the above fix - as well as the countless others has not worked for you. I thought I should share how I managed to resolve the error:

Rather than saving the form to my hard drive, and then publishing it. 
I saved it to a location on SharePoint, and published it from there.

It's worth a shot if none of the other suggested fixes has ever worked for you.